# Multi level menu with visibility control

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, navigation, managed-navigation, global-navigation

I need to implement multi level menu for Global navigation like

```
Menu Item L
     Sub Item L1
             Sub Item L11
```

In SharePoint Office 365. I have tried Structural and managed navigation, but I need mixture of these two. I mean, multi level functionality of managed navigation and security trimming of structural navigation.

Note:

1. Publishing feature is activated
2. All the menu items are on the same site. Also, I need visibility controls on menus like setting "target audience".

How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess if you specify any item permission that will not be shown anywhere in the SharePoint site. Try removing permission from an object already in the menu items. Shouldn't appear for user not having permission